# Android porting init issue

Tags: android

I have successfully ported android for sabre-sdp board,and it is booting till init process after that it is showing   (init:untrackedpid xxxx).I have all the log from booting process to end and also ihave collected logcat logs also . please go through ,if you find any solution help me out.

Thanks in advance for your support

```
  Logcat  LOGS
  ------------------------------------------------------------------

root@android:/ # logcat

--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
D/        ( 2351): init_sensors
D/        ( 2351): find sensor name mma845x
D/        ( 2351): input device 'mma845x' opened, fd = 8
E/installd( 2348): Could not create directories; exiting.
I/DEBUG   ( 2342): debuggerd: May 13 2013 18:03:14
D/        ( 2351): find sensor name mag3110
D/        ( 2351): input device 'mag3110' opened, fd = 10
D/MagDaemon( 2351): magnetic sensor calibrate daemon start
D/MagCalibrated( 2351): fl_calib = 1
D/MagDaemon( 2351): magnetic calibrate daemon set threshold 100.000000
E/keystore( 2349): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
I/Vold    ( 2340): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
D/Vold    ( 2340): Volume udisk state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
D/Vold    ( 2340): Volume extsd state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
I/Netd    ( 2341): Netd 1.0 starting
D/Vold    ( 2340): Volume extsd state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 2 (Pending)
D/Vold    ( 2340): Volume extsd state changing 2 (Pending) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
E/DirectVolume( 2340): Invalid 'PARTN' value
E/DirectVolume( 2340): Invalid 'PARTN' value
D/MDnsDS  ( 2341): MDnsSdListener::Hander starting up
D/MDnsDS  ( 2341): MDnsSdListener starting to monitor
D/MDnsDS  ( 2341): Going to poll with pollCount 1
I/mediaserver( 2346): ServiceManager: 0x41992ce0
I/AudioFlinger( 2346): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
I/CameraService( 2346): CameraService started (pid=2346)
I/FslCameraHAL( 2346): Face Back Camera is ov5640_mipi, orient is 0
I/FslCameraHAL( 2346): Face Front Camera is uvc,ov5642_camera,ov5640_camera, orient is 0
D/AndroidRuntime( 2344): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 2344): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 2344): CheckJNI is ON
I/AndroidRuntime( 2344): JNI options: '-Xjniopts:warnonly'
E/dalvikvm( 2344): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/core.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/core.jar'
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2343): SurfaceFlinger is starting
E/dalvikvm( 2344): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/core-junit.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core-junit.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/core-junit.jar'
I/SurfaceFlinger( 2343): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
E/dalvikvm( 2344): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/bouncycastle.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@bouncycastle.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar'
E/dalvikvm( 2344): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/ext.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@ext.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/ext.jar'
E/dalvikvm( 2344): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/framework.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/framework.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/telephony-common.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/mms-common.jar'
E/dalvikvm( 2344): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/android.policy.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@android.policy.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/android.policy.jar'
W/imx6.gralloc( 2343): 32bpp setting of Framebuffer catched!
E/dalvikvm( 2344): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/services.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@services.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/services.jar'
E/dalvikvm( 2344): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/apache-xml.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@apache-xml.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm( 2344): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/apache-xml.jar'
E/dalvikvm( 2344): No valid entries found in bootclasspath '/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/mms-common.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar'
E/dalvikvm( 2344): VM aborting
F/libc    ( 2344): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 2344 (zygote)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. This happens when the data partition didnt get flash properly. Watch out for indications like:
dd: writing to ‘/dev/mmcblk0’: No space left on device
or
[65561.466071] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p4): bad geometry: block count 1653768 exceeds size of device (1639176 blocks)
[65602.323558] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p4): bad geometry: block count 1653768 exceeds size of device (1639176 blocks)

Getting a larger SDCard would be a better idea.